# SQL: LIKE query on column with chr(10) or chr(13)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am doing a

```
select field1 
from tablename 
where field1 like '%xyz zrt bla bla trew%'
```

`field1` is a clob column and between the `'xyz zrt bla bla trew'` there might be new line characters like chr(10) or chr(13). So it might be  `'xyz\r\n\rzrt bla bla\n\n trew'` etc

These are being converted to one (or more spaces). So any spaces between words can be true spaces or one or more of those new line characters.

How do I take this into account in my `LIKE`?

I am using Oracle but if possible I would like to use something that works for SQL Server, etc.

Comment: Sql Server or Oracle?

Comment: @Jens I am using Oracle

Comment: What do you mean by "are being converted to spaces"? Who/what is performing this conversion, and when? In other words: do the inputs actually have the newline characters (which are definitely NOT **\r** and **\n** in Oracle, but `chr(13)` and `chr(10)` as you show correctly in your title)? Or do the inputs already have one or more spaces, and then there's no point in even mentioning the newline characters to us in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lazy solution (relying on regular expressions, which may or may not kill performance - which may or may not matter) would be something like this:

```
select field1 
from   tablename 
where  regexp_like(field1, 'xyz\s+zrt\s+bla\s+bla\s+trew')
```

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle you can use `INSTR(field1, chr(10)) > 0`

For SQL Server you can use  `field1 LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'`
or `CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), field1) > 0`

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the \n and \r with spaces first then trim the spaces and then compare. That would always work and perhaps fast enough.

However for proper speeding up the search process you can store the trimming results in a designated column "field1_trim".

Depends on your needs - storing the trimming results into a temporary table might be enough and more balanced between space/speed solution.

For example: save the result of the following query into a temporary table and then run your query on it

```
select 
  regexp_replace('[[:space:]]+', chr(32)) 
  field1_trim,
  <some unique row id to map to original table>
 from table1;
```

Comment: Did you know that the character class `[:space:]` matches not only spaces, but also newline characters like CHR(10) and CHR(13)? Your two inner calls to REPLACE are 100% unnecessary.

Comment: @mathlab, I dont access to oracle at the moment but https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm as per the specs it says "all space characters" I would expect this to be space and \t

Comment: All you need is access to Google, you don't need access to Oracle. So, the answer to my question is clearly "no". The [:space:] character class includes CHR(10), CHR(13), space, horizontal tab and vertical tab. The class [:blank:] includes just space and (horizontal) tab.

Comment: @mathguy - I trust you know what you're talking about but could you please point me to documentation or other source that would confirm your statement. Thank you

Comment: Here is the authoritative publication... the POSIX standard. Chapter 9 is about regular expressions. "Character class" is defined earlier in the standard, in Chapter 7, which is about "locale" (an important concept in regular expressions, but not only, and POSIX character classes are a broader concept than simply regular expressions). Find sub-subsection   7.3.1 LC_CTYPE  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/  and scroll down a bit to find the definition of the `space` character class.

Comment: Or, if you are satisfied with Wikipedia: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions#Character_classes

Comment: Thank you @mathguy you are absolutely correct - no need to use the translate/replace functions